# An inequality involving the norms of symmetric positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Given A and B two real symmetric positive definite matrices is it true that, for some norm $\|.\|$, this inequality holds

$$
\|AB-I\| \leq \|A^2B^2-I\| \qquad ?
$$

Comment: Is there a motivation for this question? Where does it come from?

Comment: @julien : A friend which is working on some statistic estimation project asked me. I have to admit that I don't know the background, but I tried to solve it and got stuck ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Frobenius norm $\|M\|_F=\|\operatorname{vec}(M)\|_2$ will do. Since $A,B$ are positive definite, so is $B\otimes A$. Therefore all eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix $B\otimes A + I$ are larger than $1$ and hence
\begin{align*}
\|A^2B^2-I\|_F
&=\|A(AB-I)B + AB-I\|_F\\
&=\|(B\otimes A + I)\operatorname{vec}(AB-I)\|_2\\
&\ge\|\operatorname{vec}(AB-I)\|_2\\
&=\|AB-I\|_F.
\end{align*}
Equality holds if and only if $AB=I$.

Comment: awesome ! Is it something classical or you just come out with that ?

Comment: @Student I just tried a few norms. Numerical experiements showed that the inequality holds for some other matrix norms, too, such as the spectral norm, but I simply picked the one that makes the inequality the easiest to prove. So I don't know if this is a known result or not, or whether the inequality holds for a broader class of norms.